IAM Policy List Files Access Denied When Conditions Added
I have an IAM policy associated with an access group in an S3 compatible host. If I grant access to a bucket as a resource, it works as intended. But if I add a condition like a path or a prefix, I get access denied trying to list the bucket contents. I'm trying to only give access to certain files inside the bucket.
This is the json for the policy:
{
    "type": "access",
    "control": {
        "grant": {
            "roles": [
                {
                    "role_id": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Reader"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "resource": {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "operator": "stringEquals",
                "value": "ID-12345",
                "key": "accountId"
            },
            {
                "value": "cloud-object-storage",
                "operator": "stringEquals",
                "key": "serviceName"
            },
            {
                "value": "bucket-name",
                "operator": "stringEquals",
                "key": "resource"
            },
            {
                "value": "bucket",
                "operator": "stringEquals",
                "key": "resourceType"
            }
        ]
    },
    "rule": {
        "operator": "or",
        "conditions": [
            {
                "key": "{{resource.attributes.prefix}}",
                "operator": "stringMatch",
                "value": "folder-name"
            },
            {
                "key": "{{resource.attributes.path}}",
                "operator": "stringMatch",
                "value": "folder-name"
            }
        ]
    },
    "pattern": "attribute-based-condition:resource:literal-and-wildcard",
    "subject": {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "key": "access_group_id",
                "operator": "stringEquals",
                "value": "AccessGroupId-12345"
            }
        ]
    }
}


I've tried adding a stringExists=false for path, prefix, and delimiter because reader actions don't send this, and it didn't change anything.
